# Blender Boolean Export as .obj wired triangle glitch (And if I can bake 2 objects with modifier into 1)

Tags: modifiers, export, obj

I made simple 2 objects with Boolean Modifier and export them as .obj (I only selected object that has Modifier). When I open .obj file with any viewer it got wired glitch with triangles mashing up all around. I tried different methods but they all result same. I recorded short 3min video to explain my problem.

thank you for support!

https://youtu.be/PwWms-QI8Mc

Comment: Update (Still not solved): https://youtu.be/slQ4PDCU3ew

Comment: Have you tried to open the OBJ with Blender and see how it looks? or is there any reason to use a 3d Viewer?

Comment: https://justpaste.it/3p6m3 This is website called 3dviewer.net, I got same result.