# Exporting Mesh Made with Boolean Difference leads to Triangle Glitch

Tags: modifiers, export

This question is pretty much identical to [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196153/blender-boolean-export-as-obj-wired-triangle-glitch-and-if-i-can-bake-2-object), but I just made this account and cannot seem to comment on other posts yet, so I had to make a new one.

In short, I've been trying to do very simple boolean subtractions, and it looks fine in the Blender viewport, but when exporting I end up with a mesh with distorted faces.

For example, the following Arch was made with a cube primitive, cylinder primitive, and the Boolean Difference modifier applied to the cube with the cylinder selected as subtracting object:

[image: Simple Archway Made with Boolean Difference]

However, when I export in either the .obj or .fbx file formats, I get the following in the Windows 3D Viewer:

[image: Distorted Archway Export]

For the record, I *am* making sure to apply the modifier, and I deleted the leftover cylinder after applying the boolean modifier.

I initially experienced this on Blender 2.93, so I downloaded the latest version to see if the issue was fixed by an update. I am now on Blender 3.0.0 and I'm still experiencing the issue. Currently on a Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit machine. Any help/guidance would be appreciated, and please let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Comment: did you try to add a triangulate modifier in blender before exporting yet?

Comment: I forgot to try that (mostly because the original post had tried it and it didn't work, so I'd written it off in my head), and it worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: don't worry, you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Marten Zander for pointing this out; adding the triangulate modifier to the object after applying the Boolean Difference modifier solves the export issue completely!